# Why does const_cast and static_cast to const reference have no effect?

Tags: c++, static-cast, const-cast

In the following code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        const int i = 8;
        int j = 90;
        const_cast<int &>(i)  = 10;
        static_cast<const int&> (j);
        j = 200;
        cout << " i = " << i << endl;
        cout << " j = " << j << endl;
   }
```

I thought the output will be

```
i = 10
j = 90
```

But the actual output was

```
i = 8
j = 200
```

So the casting did not work ?

Comment: I recommend the excellent documentation at [https://en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) for a first approach. Only if you cannot find an answer there, ask here. In this case, you would have found [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) ...

Comment: @StoryTeller: Nice duplicate for future research purposes. I've change the title; to me this one is well-asked and could be helpful in future searches.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I'm always for good signposts. You won't believe how lost I got whilst on a trip in the country recently...

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour of `const_cast<int &>(i) = 10;` is *undefined*. That's because `i` is originally `const` and you are casting away the `const`-ness *and* attempting to write to the object. So any output could be observed.

`static_cast<const int&> (j);` is a no-op: it doesn't somehow transform `j` into a `const` type. The subsequent `j = 200;` is a trivial assignment